# Unable to convert Year/month to date

Tags: r, date

Undoubtedly I am making some kind of stupid mistake here...haven't touched R in a while.

I have several hundred thousand rows of data imported from an SQL database.  One of the columns is a year/month date that imports as character data.  I would like to convert it to a date.  From other answers here I have tried
`as.Date(<col>, format="%Y/%m/01")` and `as.Date(paste(<col>,"/01"), format="%Y/%m/%d")` and in both cases I wind up with a column of `NA`'s

```
dates <- c("2014/09", "2015/09")
blah <- as.data.frame(dates)
blah$dates <- as.Date(blah$dates, format="%Y/%m/01")
# OR
blah$dates <- as.Date(paste(blah$dates,"/01"), format="%Y/%m/%d")

blah
  dates
1  <NA>
2  <NA>
```

So where am I going wrong

Comment: Change `paste()` to `paste0()` and it should work.

Comment: Or `lubridate::ym(blah$dates)`

Comment: jerH, the dupe links should provide more context for your problem, and SamR's recommendation to use `paste0` instead should also resolve it. If there are still problems, please [edit] your question, add the necessary context, then @-ping me and we can sort through the differences.

Comment: `paste0` that was it...knew I was doing something stupid